# FatFree, form data validation

Tags: forms, validation

I see FatFree has `Audit` class for data validation, but there are no methods
to check for example min or max length allowed, or if field should be
mandatory or not.

Should I extend `Audit` class, to provide that abillity? Is that right way to
do it?

Comment: Always wanted to use this MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Right, if you need more than that [here](http://fatfreeframework.com/audit) I would just extend audit class.